# unable to connect to database on AWS

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, amazon-web-services

actually I have my website build with Joomla hosted on hostmonster

but all Joomla website need a database support to run this database is on AWS
 configuration files need to be updated for that
 I have to change host address
I put the IP (of AWS host) in host but it displayed "unable to connect to database MySQL"
 can u help me out
 ?????????

Comment: Is this solution performed well with scalability?

Comment: YES I tested it in production environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have database on server B and website on server A(say it has IP 192.234.12.1)

on cpanel whitelist the IP of server B

and create a new user having sufficient privileges in database (say this user is test)

then create this user as test@192.234.12.1

Answer (score 1):

Look into your security settings for your server on AWS.  Most likely you will need to open up port 3306 on your firewall.  You can do this using the AWS Console.

I'd strongly advise reading through the [security guidelines for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/security-guidelines.html).